# Session expire during data saving to database

Tags: java, jsp, session

I am trying to upload an excel file and save its data to database. The excel contain 4690 rows of data, the session is expired during data is inserting to the data base.  In my `web.xml` file i had added these lines.

```
<session-config>
<session-timeout>15</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

I need to extend session of this particular page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the session timeout in your javacode to override the default timeout:

```
request.getSession().setMaxInactiveInterval(timeoutInSeconds);
```

Can that be a workable solution for you? Please let me know!

:)

Comment: This one helps to extend the time out. But I am facing an issue, some files are small and some are too big. is there any way to extend session time accordingly.

Comment: What about adding a test to check the size of the file and setting the timeout based on this test something like

`
if (isLargeFile()) {
  request.getSession().setMaxInactiveInterval(LONG_TIMEOUT);
} else {
    request.getSession().setMaxInactiveInterval(SHORT_TIMEOUT);
}
`

Comment: Thank you I will try that one.